# Jade compiling: 'Unexpected Token "dot"'

Tags: jquery, node.js, compilation, pug

I'm trying to compile a very simple Jade template:

```
p hi
```

Here's the corresponding Javascript (JQuery is loaded in):

```
var jade = require('jade');

$('#container').html(jade.compile('../jade/gen.jade'));
```

It throws the Error `Error: unexpected token "dot"` on execution. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jade.compile takes a source string, not a filename.  try jade.compile('p hi') or jade.compileFile('../jade/gen.jade') instead.